# Import global module in django if I have the same module in my app

Tags: python, django

How do i import a module(e.g. mysite/constants.py) defined at my project level while there is one module at my app level also(e.g. mysite/myapp/constants.py).

How do i import global constants mysite/myapp/view.py ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
from mysite import constants
```

If you want to also import the one that you have in your app, you can use `as` like below:

```
from mysite import constants as mysite_constants
from mysite.myapp import constants as myapp_constants
```

Answer (score 0):

You could alias your modules on import

```
from mysite import constants as site_const
```

Or just import the parent module, and use the submodule with dot notation

```
import mysite
print(mysite.constants.SOME_CONSTANT)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you enable absolute imports in Python 2, then `import constants` will import `constants` from the project directory (which is on the python path). This is the same as the behaviour in Python 3.

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import constants  # import project-level constants
```

You can then import `myapp.constants` with either of the following:

```
import myapp.constants as myapp_constants
import .constants as myapp_constants
```